# Finding unrelated numbers that are awfully close

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking for a nice example of two numbers that are really close to each other, but that have no obvious relationship with each other.

Both numbers should be constructed in a "neat" way; i.e. using only functions (such as Sin, Power, Log etc.), integers (smaller is better), e and pi.

The difference between the numbers should be at max $0.001$ (but smaller is better) and both numbers should be between $1$ and $10$.

An example that is nice (but not close enough) would be:

$$\pi+\sqrt{2}\approx(\frac{7}{6})^{10}$$

Question 1: Who can find a "neat" example?

Question 2: What would more generally be a good strategy to find such numbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence

Comment: Using all digits once : $e\simeq(1+9^{-4^{7\times6}})^{3^{2^{85}}}$ is that close enough ?

Comment: @zwim How to you know how close they are?!? Even mathematica generates a "overflow in computation"

Comment: @GambitSquared By using a tool more powerful than mathematica, pencil and paper and $(1+\frac 1n)^n\to e$.

Comment: $e^{\pi \sqrt {163}}$ differs from its nearest integer by less than $10^{-12}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Hehe, nice. That nearest integer is $24\times10939058860032031$ of which the last is prime :)

Comment: Interesting.....My copy of Mathematical Recreations And Essays by Rousse-Balle and Coxeter is in storage so I couldn't look up the name associated with that factoid. It was a 19th century "calculating prodigy" who became a mathematician, who observed it when he was quite old but still a formidable calculator.

Comment: @GambitSquared Define "no obvious relationship"! With the continued fraction method you can easily get approximations like $\pi\approx\frac{355}{113}$ which is good to $6$ digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Feb 2005, Ed Pegg instigated a quest for such approximations, which he called "keen approximations". Results are shown [here](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/34-Keen%20Approximations/mathgames_02_14_05.html).

From that page, two examples from Charles Hermite, exploiting the fact that -163 is a [Heegner number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeegnerNumber.html):

$$\left(\frac{\log(640320^3+744)}{\pi}\right)^2=163+2.321\times 10^{-29}$$

$$\frac{\log((640320^3+744)^2-393768)}{\sqrt{652}}=\pi-9.303\times 10^{-47}$$

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a little difficulty finding my old result. :)